# What's the best UML diagramming tool?

Tags: uml, diagram, modeling

I'm trying to choose a tool for creating UML diagrams of all flavours. Usability is a major criteria for me, but I'd still take more power with a steeper learning curve and be happy. Free (as in beer) would be nice, but I'd be willing to pay if the tool's worth it. What should I be using?

Comment: [IBM Rational Modeler](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/modeler/) has a free version, and if you want more features, you can pay for the corporate version. I'm quite satisfied with it.

Comment: You can try the [Eclipse Modeling Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/junor) distribution. It's Eclipse, and it's Free!

Comment: For text-based visual model generation I would recommend yuml.me or plantuml.

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Some context: Recently for graduate school I researched UML tools for usability and UML comprehension in general for an independent project.  I also model/architect for a living.

The previous posts have too many answers and not enough questions.  A common misunderstanding is that UML is about creating diagrams.  Sure, diagrams are important, but really you are creating a model.  Here are the questions that should be answered as each vendor product/solution does some things better than others.  *Note:  The listed answers are my view as the best even if other products support a given feature or need.*

- Are you modeling or drawing? (Drawing - [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), free implementations, and [Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/visio/))
- Will you be modeling in the future? (For basic modeling - Community editions of pay products)
- Do you want to formalize your modeling through profiles or meta-models? OCL? ([Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com), RSM, [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/))
- Are you concerned about model portability, XMI support? ([GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com), [Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com), [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/), [Altova](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html))
- Do you have an existing set of documents that you need to work with? (Depends on the documents)
- Would you want to generate code stubs or full functioning code?([GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com), [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/), [Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com), [Altova](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html))
- Do you need more mature processes such as use case management, pattern creation, asset creation, RUP integration, etc? (RSA/RSM/IBM Rational Products)

Detailed Examples:  IBM Rational Software Architect did not implement UML 2.0 all the way when it comes to realizes type relationships when creating a UML profile, but Visual Paradigm and Sparx got it right. 
Ok, that was way too detailed, so a simpler example would be [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), which has no code generation features and focuses on drawing more than the modeling aspect of UML. 
 [Sparx](http://www.sparxsystems.com) and [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/) do UML really well and generate code well, however, hooking into project lifecycles and other process is where RSM/RSA is strong. 
Watch out for closed or product specific code generation processes or frameworks as you could end up stuck with that product.

This is a straight brain dump so a couple details may not be perfect, however, this should provide a general map to the questions and solutions to looking into.

NEW - Found a good list of many UML tools with descriptions.  [Wiki UML Tool List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools)

Comment: could you please include a link to your evaluation if it is able to be published. I recently did a simpler evaluation for a client and picked Sparx EA (for models, codegen, code import, drawing, extensible) which is lean enough it still runs very nicely on low-spec Macs under Virtual PC.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I actually did research informally around the tools. For my main research I did not even use a UML tool, just paper and a pencil.  I have continued looking a these tools.  Each have their strengths.  RSM/RSA in my opinion would not run very well on low spec macs for example.

Comment: ArgoUML == NO SUPPORT to Sequence Diagrams

Comment: @Lucas & Ted: ArgoUML has the sequence diagram feature, as well as code generation. (0.30)

Comment: For a handy UML diagram editor for Windows see [Cadifra UML Editor](http://www.cadifra.com)

Comment: Excuse me but what is the difference between modeling and drawying ? Or do you mean that modeling is drawing different types of diagrams that are connected to each other while drawing is just drawing static diagrams that has no effect on other diagrams if modified and vice versa ?

Comment: Hey Ted, you mention that you studied this in a grad school project.  did you end up publishing a paper / report, and is it available?

Comment: I saw that GenMyModel is cloud-based, the models are designed in a web-browser. I'm convinced the collaboration should be another relevant item in this answer: sharing, real-time modeling, version management,  repository... I tried out most of the mainstream desktop uml tools. Not easy for several team members to work together on the same model. Hopefully online modeling is going to change the way many IT people evaluate  and use (UML) modeling in their day-to-day development projects. I'd gladly read more about online modeling. Does anyone know if it's an ongoing trend?

Comment: Hi @Georges! Does GenMyModel fully implement UML specification?and which version of specification?

Comment: Hi @Chriss, GenMyModel presently implements a part of the UML 2 (3.0.0) specification. It supports class diagrams and use case diagrams :)

Answer (score 99):

For sequence diagrams, only, try [websequencediagrams.com](http://websequencediagrams.com). It's a freemium (free for the basic tasks, paid for advanced features) product, and lets you quickly bang out a diagram without any fussing around with lines and stencils.

```
Alice->Bob: Authentication Request
note left of Bob: Bob thinks about it
Bob->Alice: Authentication Response
```

[image]

Comment: It's interesting but I'm not sure I see the value of it being web based - surely it would be better to have it on your PC and you can save files etc - and a GUI, drag and drop is surely easier than scripting you have to know.

Comment: Really great site! However, for real usage I'm with Simon: can't see me using it on a live project.

Comment: @Sean/Simon: It has PDF export andpermalinks

Comment: @Simon - it's hardly scripting. You type in a simple text description of the interaction. And you can easily copy and paste the text description to your PC, export PDFs and/or save the images by right-clicking in the browser. I use it on work projects.

Comment: Why is this voted so high why it does not answer the question?  Oh well, I agree it is a nifty website.  The first line in the question says "creating UML diagrams of all flavours.".  I would vote it down, but I am weak, so I will just comment.

Comment: +1. I came in to share this one as well, realizing that it doesn't answer the question in full. Sequence diagrams have always seemed a little awkward / out-of-place when juxtaposed with the rest of UML, but they're UML nonetheless. In my opinion, sequence diagrams are the most immediately valuable part of UML.

Comment: How do you tell it "No, your other left."?

Comment: An anonymous user suggests that you could also use [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/), which is a free Java/Graphviz tool for generating UML diagrams from text. It's very likely that's the tool that this website uses behind the scenes.

Answer (score 46):

For me it's Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems. A very rounded UML tool for a very reasonable price.

Very strong feature list including: integrated project management, baselining, export/import (including export to html), documentation generation from the model, various templates (Zachman, TOGAF, etc.), IDE plugins, code generation (with IDE plugins available for Visual Studio, Eclipse & others), automation API - the list goes on.

Oh yeah, don't forget support for source control directly from inside the tool (SVN, CVS, TFS & SCC).

I would also stay away from Visio - you only get diagrams, not a model. Rename a class in one place in a UML modelling tool and you rename in all places. This is *not* the case in Visio!

Comment: After trying a dozen or two UML tools, I've also settled for EA by Sparx. I'm using only 5-10% of its capabilities, though... :-)

Comment: Is it just me or is layout management in EA terrible at least with UML classes? Hard to resize things and show only what i want. Using default layouts puts classes all over the place. Tool looks amazing but layout is really giving me a hard time.

Comment: I use Visio for physical database modeling (admitting it's not perfect for the task) and this is not true. If I rename a table its name is replaced in all diagrams (inside the same VSD of course). BTW I use Sparx for UML modeling.

Answer (score 45):

For my simple & short UML working,
I've used this tool:

StarUML - http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/

Great free software for UML drawing.

---

Although the original Star UML is no longer maintained, there's now a fork called [White Star UML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/), which is actively developed.

Comment: is staruml still under active development?

Comment: Unfortunately looks like it is Windows-only. Being cross-platform is one of my first requirements when it comes to choosing a tool for my team.

Comment: Unfortunately the project seems to be dead. Check the recent discussion at source forge for more details: http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1879127&forum_id=510442

Comment: StarUML doesn't recognize the new syntax of java1.6. It's dead.

Comment: yes it is...but i think it doesnt have Sequence Diagram...

Comment: someone picked it up: http://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/

Comment: StarUML is unusable. Crashes on start up on WinXP.

Comment: I've been using this tool for several years, and get really excited that some one has pick it up and keep releasing new versions. Wonderful tool! +1

Answer (score 31):

As I usually use UML more as a communication tool rather than a modeling tool I sometimes have the need to flex the language a bit, which makes the strict modeling tools quite unwieldy. Also, they tend to have a large overhead for the occasional drawing. This also means I don't give tools that handle round-trip modeling well any bonus points. With this in mind...

When using [Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/visio), I tend to use [these](http://softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html) stencils for my UMLing needs (the built in kind of suck). It could be that I have grown used to it as it is the primary diagramming tool at my current assignment.

[OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/pro/) also has some UML stencils built in and more are available at [Graffletopia](http://graffletopia.com/categories/programming), but I wouldn't recommend that as a diagramming tool as it has too many quirks (quirks that are good for many things, but not UML). Free trial though, so by all means... :)

I've been trying out [MagicDraw](http://magicdraw.com/) a bit, but while functional, I found the user interface distracting.

Otherwise i find the [Topcased](http://topcased.gforge.enseeiht.fr/) an interesting project (or group of projects). Last I used it it still had some bugs, but it worked, and seems to have evolved nicely since. Works great on any Eclipse-enabled platform. Free as in speech and beer :)

As for the diagramming tool [Dia](http://www.gnome.org/projects/dia/), it's quite ugly (interface and resulting drawings), but it does get the job done. An interesting modeling tool free alternative is [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/index.php), but I haven't really used it much.

I definitely agree with [mashi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool#24944) that whiteboards are great (together with a digital camera or cellphone).

Probably some of the nicest tools I've used belong to the [Rational](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/sw-bycategory/subcategory/SW710.html) family of tools.

Comment: +1 for Dia - it's a nice little tool, and is absoloutely _great_ for flowcharts. However, Umbrello crashes on me quite a bit (that and Qt is a mound of cruft anyway).

Answer (score 24):

You may be looking for an automated tool that will automatically generate a lot of stuff for you. But here's a free, generally powerful diagramming tool useful not only for UML but for all kinds of diagramming tasks. It accepts as input and outputs to a wide variety of commonly used file formats. It's called yEd, and it's [worth a look](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html)

Comment: The layout looks great, it is fast and it seems to be usable in 5 minutes. One great feature is that you can choose how to lay the diagram out: hierarchical, organic, UML style, circular or tree like. It does it in a blink of an eye. So far I have some reservations for software written in Java but this just changed my belief :)

Answer (score 21):

[Visual Paradigm for UML http://content.usa.visual-paradigm.com/websiteimages/images/products/vpuml60/vpumltitle.gif](http://content.usa.visual-paradigm.com/websiteimages/images/products/vpuml60/vpumltitle.gif)

I'm very fond of [Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/) It's very powerful and has a free [Community Edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/communityedition.jsp) and cheap [Personal Edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/personaledition.jsp) as well.

[Agilian http://content.usa.visual-paradigm.com/websiteimages/images/products/ag10/agtitle.gif](http://content.usa.visual-paradigm.com/websiteimages/images/products/ag10/agtitle.gif)

For Agile modeling there's also [Agilian](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/ag/) which is a bit more flexible, adds extra features to support smartboards and knows mind-mapping as well.

The thing I like most about their products is the flexibility. I'm using Enterprise Architect at work nowadays but I think it's not smart enough. I want to be able to quick-brainstorm some sequence diagrams and have the application keep my model up-to-date in the background, something VPUML does a very good job at.

In my opinion it's way better than Enterprise Architect, though that is a great tool as well :)

Comment: I've used most of the major UML Tools (most of which extensively)(Rational Rose, Tau, Rhapsody, Enterprise Architect, Visio, and several others) and accidentally stumbled upon Visual Paradigm, which I had never heard of. It blows all the others out of the water. It has its' quirks but it is not that annoying to work with (compared to the others which are very annoying) and is very powerful.

Comment: Definitely Visual Paradigm. I have been using it for some time now, and also recently evaluated other UML modelling tools (free and commercial ones), and Visual Paradigm is simply the best when it comes to usability and clear UI structure. Also, all the diagrams seem to be absolutely standards compliant (sadly, not all modeling tools are). I can tell, as I have also recently worked through the UML, MOF, XMI standards. VP is the absolute favourite to me.

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at [BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr): multiplatform (QT), works pretty well and supports colaborative work.

> BOUML is a free UML 2 tool box (under development) allowing you to specify and generate code in C++, Java, Idl, Php and Python.
>
> BOUML runs under Unix/Linux/Solaris, MacOS X(Power PC and Intel) and Windows.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOUML):

> The releases prior to version 4.23 are free software licensed under GPL. BOUML 5 and later is proprietary software.

Comment: @Silvia +1 for recommending BOUML. It's a shame that that the developer has been driven to stop developing it. Unlike other tools which look more like toys and are incomplete, this one is actually capable of reading existing code (reverse-engineering) in several languages and also import from Rational (IBM) Rose and other UML tools. It is our loss that he ceased developing it.

Comment: In fact, development has just been stopped in his free form, the main developer now uses fee licenses, keeping the tool updated.

Comment: In fact, there is a fork of last open-source release currently in development. Although it's still not quite there, some stuff is working and working better than in the original. Google "Douml"

Comment: Also, I'd very much like some help in development 'cause there's a ton of stuff to fix/do and there is only one me :( Atm the project is fully Qt4 compatible, but not all plugouts are working due to porting bugs which are kinda hard too weed out not being original developer.

Answer (score 18):

If you're looking to get out the door and working on UML without having to learn a complex new tool I would check out [Violet UML](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php).  I've used it to some pretty great success in the past.

Comment: Screenshot: http://img516.imageshack.us/img516/2069/violeti.jpg .It's by far the best free uml tool in my view

Comment: Wow, just tried that out and it is awesome. Only thing on my wishlist is some way to redirect arrows.  Ie give them a draggable mid point.

Answer (score 17):

[PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/index.html) is an open-source markup-language-to-UML-diagram tool in Java that deserves to be mentioned here. It ranks high on the usability scale  because of its intuitive syntax for the various diagrams and diagram components.

Answer (score 14):

[Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) is a possible choice. It's definitely not the best tool, but it is functional.

Comment: Screenshots featuring UML mode here: https://live.gnome.org/Dia/Screenshots

Comment: It's an easy to use tool and ideal for my purposes anyway (diagramming only, no code generation/integration, primarily class diagrams). Runs on Linux, Winodws and MacOSX - the file format can be used across platforms.

Answer (score 13):

Enterprise Architect from Sparx systems is the best tool I've used. A bit expensive at $199 (professional edition), but IMO it's worth it.

Comment: I really enjoy using Enterprise Architect.  I don't consider it all that expensive, especially for professional use.  And when you compare it in price and features to rational rose it wins hands down.

Comment: having just done an eval for a client, I agree - $199 is superb value considering it includes code import and codegen! Nothing came close in cost-effectiveness.

Comment: btw, professional Visio costs MUCH more

Comment: For a company 200$ is just half day-man. Really cheap.

Answer (score 13):

I will add [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/) which I haven't tried yet, but have been selected at my office to start doing diagrams.
Looks simple, diagrams aren't sexy, but it seems quite complete with regard to the kind of diagrams you can do. Seems to have good export capabilities too (important!), is flexible can support custom components) and can be used as Eclipse plugin.

Comment: I just started using UMLet today - in short, it's simple, fast and easy.

Answer (score 11):

[Astah UML](http://astah.net/) (ex-JUDE) is pretty good.

Comment: Missing features: naming of initial and final state, nesting of hierarchical statemachine diagrams in the same diagram (w.o. linking diagrams). Whats good: Continuous improvements, author commited to UML spec, more than just a drawing tool. Runs on UNIX. Has a long way to go, to bring it to the "Enterprise Architect" level of functionality.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't been able to find a top-notch free UML diagramming tool, but if you're interested in pure diagramming, as opposed to round-trip-engineering, I'd go with Microsoft Visio. If you want full round-trip engineering, Rational Rose.

This [list of UML tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools) on Wikipedia might also come in handy.

Answer (score 10):

Pen and paper. If you can get the scan into a vector format, that may be useful when making minor amendments.

Comment: With the same pen you can write the code on another paper and scan it. Thank to the available `OCR` technology, you can convert it to the text later for the further use! (BTW, I also use pen & paper for diagrams just because it's faster and I also like drawing very much from childhood!)

Answer (score 10):

You should try Creately. Runs in your browser and can do team collaboration.

supports sequence diagrams, class, ER, usecase etc. works great and has a free version available.

[Creately.com](http://creately.com)

Answer (score 9):

You can also check out [Lucid Chart](http://www.lucidchart.com) for uml and other types of diagramming.

Comment: Wow.  LucidChart is awesome for this.  I've seen their flowcharting stuff before, but these UML tools are easy to use and pretty complete for what I need.

Comment: I also found LucidChart to be great for drawing up quick, nice looking UML diagrams. The free account lets you have an unlimited amount of diagrams, also you can export to PNG, JPEG, PDF, area selection or entire document. Impressed!

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget [yuml.me](http://yuml.me), I love it.

Comment: I find it difficult to represent anything complex using yuml.

Answer (score 4):

I like VisualParadigm mentioned before in this thread. It's powerful and easy to use I think it gives most power comparing to other tools.

If you need something simple, quick and easy (and free) there is a great tool called [**UMLet**](http://www.umlet.com) - **I highly recommend this**. I've tried many of UML diagramming tools and this the simplest one (and it still allows to do great diagrams). This is my choice:)

Answer (score 4):

http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Why? Because of i need uml in code

Answer (score 4):

In my practice i use [Sequence Diagram Editor](http://www.sequencediagrameditor.com/). it is really fast and helpful tool. the one thing i don't like about it is that it is commercial product, not free.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously if you are serious about UML in the long run you need to use a software UML tool like the ones suggested in the other answers, but I've found that a whiteboard is one of the best tools for UML diagramming, especially during the design phase, or when you are exploring different alternatives.  Nothing beats a whiteboard for speed/flexibility in my mind.  They are also great for collaboration assuming you are collocated physically.

Answer (score 3):

In [my opinion](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2008/11/25/staruml-and-argouml-compared/) **StarUML** is the best.

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe no one has mentioned NetBeans UML Editor, it's great and satisfied all of my Java based UML requirments.

This after I tested JDeveloper UML, ArgoUML and StarUML.

Answer (score 3):

I recently conducted a poll "[What UML Tools do you use](http://www.solitarygeek.com/general/what-uml-tools-do-you-use/)?" in my blog. NetBeans UML was was the top opensource choice and Enterprise Architect was the top commercial choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can create UML class, sequence, component, use case, and activity diagrams in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. You can link these diagrams to Team Foundation work items so you can plan and track development and test work. You can also create sequence, dependency graphs, and layer diagrams from code and use Architecture Explorer to browse and explore your solution.

I've posted more links on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275715/esther-fan) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [MagicDraw](http://magicdraw.com/) or [Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/). Both offer community editions that, of course, don't span the full feature range, but may well be sufficient if you want to create diagrams only and not generate code or do full round-trip engineering.

Answer (score 2):

Rational and Together/J are best-of-breed products, but expensive.

In my experience, I've enjoyed Eclipse Omondo and Sparx Enterprise Architect.  Omondo integrates nicely with Eclipse for code generation, and has a very intuitive feel.  However, it is strongly tied to Java.  Sparx is a good tool for the price point, but lacks the full range of UML 2.0 diagrams.

Do NOT bother with Poseidon.  It is buggy, bloated, and unusuable for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 2):

For sequence diagrams you can also try [Trace Modeler](http://www.tracemodeler.com/index.html). It's not free but it has a great interface, very friendly and productive. You can use it on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try [alt text http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/images/products/logos/EA.png](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html)

But, It is NOT free

It has amazing features.. Check the [screenshots](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/screenshots.html) here.

And they have [alt text http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/images/products/logos/MDGIntVS-268x73.png](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/mdg/int/vs/index.html)  and  [alt text http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/images/products/logos/MDGIntEclipse-223x73.png](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/mdg/int/eclipse/index.html)tooo..

Answer (score 1):

Visual Paradigm for UML or Dia are good options

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on UML standards since 1999 and may tell you that Sparx Enterprise Architect should not be considered as a UML tool as it does not follow UML 2 specification. Its diagrams look as UML but names of the properties and the way as they specified are not following UML standard. MagicDraw and IBM RSA are the true UML tool on the market so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Modelio Free Edition](http://www.modeliosoft.com/).
It support UML2, BPMN, SOA and XMI. It is simple to use and their forum is very active.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/).  It's not the best tool I've ever used, but it's one of the better free ones I've seen.  It's a little slow because it's written in Java, but it let's you do some basic UML diagrams with relative ease.

Comment: I would say nay on that, I butted my head against that wall for a month and there's got to be something better.  Far too clunky and an un-intuitive UI.

Comment: Argo is still primative but is the only truely open source UML tool available.

Comment: it's not slow because it's written in Java, it's slow because it's a work in progress and I believe the developers have had any time to work on performance issues.

Comment: @Martin: refresh your research on actual OS UML tools, there are new tools, especially BoUML, which is great.

Comment: ArgoUML cannot copy-paste objects and even undo!

Comment: Been working on it for a few days and the lack of undo is a real pain ! Specially I ctrl+s all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is a decent tool for UML 1.4 and has recently (Autumn 2008) been receiving some much needed maintainance updates.

Answer (score 0):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org).

I used this for my thesis and it is well-designed: maybe it has too much feature not [very important](http://argouml.tigris.org/features.html#critics) but I prefer have some uselee feature than don't have some useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

**I strongly recommend** [BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/). It's a free UML modelling application, which:

- is extremely fast (**fastest** UML tool ever created, check out [benchmarks](http://bouml.free.fr/benchmark.html)),
- has rock solid C++, Java, PHP and others import support,
- is multiplatform (Linux, Windows, other OSes),
- has a great SVG export support, which is important, because viewing large graphs in vector format, which scales fast in e.g. Firefox, is very convenient (you can quickly switch between "birds eye" view and class detail view),
- is full featured, impressively intensively developed (look at [development history](http://bouml.free.fr/historic.html), it's hard to believe that such fast progress is possible).
- supports plugins, has modular architecture (this allows [user contributions](http://bouml.free.fr/contrib.html), looks like BOUML community is forming up)

Believe me, there is no better tool. StarUML is a retarded turtle compared to BOUML. ArgoUML simply doesn't work. Dia is a ergonomy^-1 software.

Comment: -1 "fastest ever created", "rock solid", "great", "impressively intensively developed", "no better tool" plus bashing other solutions... It's nice having a detailed description but there is way too much promotion in there.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in my two bits here, but I found ArgoUML to be very useful.  It takes a little while to get used to it and its a bit buggy (last I checked it was in version .29 or so) but it works pretty well once you get used to it.  It handles all types of UML diagrams, which is why I prefer it.  Also, its made by tigris, the same people who made subclipse, an SVN repository plug-in for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model at diagram level and also have a clean metamodel the new Omondo build allows live synchronization between MOF and UML Diagrams.
Just amazing to see my diagram and the xmi live synchronized each time I change something in my diagram and the model is changed. What is most incredible is that the model is also the metamodel and the MOF because everything is lived synchronized. Very powerful new concept for my point of view.

I also like Java code annotation and JPA support in the class diagram and in the model. I don't know any other tool having these 2 incredible features !!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Sybase PowerDesigner

http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner

Description:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerDesigner

It is a vary powerful tool but so is the price!

Answer (score 0):

The [TopCoder UML Tool](http://www.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/TopCoder+UML+Tool) is a very good free UML tool.

Answer (score 0):

For sequence diagrams there is free java based [Quick Sequence Diagram Editor](http://sdedit.sourceforge.net/). The sequence is written in text editor and then rendered by QSDE engine. It exports to variety of vector and bitmap file formats.

Answer (score 0):

[Violet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/violet/)

Free, and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Software Ideas Modeler](http://www.softwareideas.net/). It has a lot of features and an intuitive GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried MagicDraw and it is very good, only the community edition though.

Also I have tried omondo, it looks fantastic but it is very expensive for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for TopCoder UML Tool after I had tried most of other free tools.
My reasons are:

1) The tool can save UML diagrams in the human-readable format XMI, so the file can be fed to the version control system easily.

2) Support of Undo/Redo (this is the reason I've discharged ArgoUML).

3) The diagram is kept in one single file, and not linked tightly with "workspace" or "project".

StarUML is also good, though is old. Unfortunatley it is not developed/maintained any longer.

Answer (score 0):

In my career I often needed to draw UML diagrams and generate Java code. I found [MagicDraw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagicDraw_UML) most appealing and I'm a happy user. I think their licensing model is fair because it allows to pay for what you need. I prefer it to other products I used in my (distant) past: ArgoUML, Poseidon, Rational Rose, Dia. Be aware that my experiences on other products are obsolete and have maybe significantly improved or changed their licensing model. Maybe you should start with an open-source tool and decide later whether to spend some bucks.

With [MagicDraw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagicDraw_UML) you can document your code by generating diagrams from code. You can also model first, then generate the code. It also integrates well with several IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

I use [gmodeler.com](http://gmodeler.com).  It just does class diagrams.

Good things

- Very simple feature set.  Great UI. Very easy to use.
- Attractive UI.
- Don't have to login/create an account
- Can save diagrams
- Free

Bad things

- Hard to collaborate -- have to export to xml (I don't care)
- Can't access diagrams from any machine because it saves to your browser (I don't care)
- Can't export as image or pdf (I can take a screen shot)
- Can't generate code for most languages
- Very simple feature set.  (I don't care)
- Each class has an 'Event' list which I don't need and I can't get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use [Pacestar UML Diagrammer](http://www.pacestar.com/uml/index.html). It helps you generate UML 2.0 diagrams **quickly**, **easily**, **flexible** AND commonly understood notation.

I used it in many projects and I'm very satisfied. And too it doesn't use much of memory and space just 6 Mo of Hard Disk.

And the most feature that I like it very much is that I can copy diagrams from the editor and paste them in MS Word... so when I need to edit a specific diagram, just I click on and it will be opened in the editor and by closing it, the updates had been done in MS Word document.