# Learning Eclipse MDT-UML2 Sequence Diagrams

Tags: eclipse, uml, mdt

Are there any tutorials or documentation files for drawing Sequence Diagrams with Eclipse MDT-UML2?

I can't put a Lifeline on the page.  It took me 10 minutes to figure out that I first have to make a big Iteraction, and then I can put Lifelines into it.

I can't figure out how to make the Participant box wider in the lifeline.  Any name more than 4 characters is too wide for the box.  When I do the obvious thing of clicking and dragging the handles, the box springs back to its original size.

I can add a Message by clicking "Message" in the pallette and click-dragging an arrow from line Lifeline to another.  Now I have an arrow labeled "1: *".  I've tried every way I can think of to change that name:  double-clicking on it, shift-clicking, ctrl-clicking, changing Name in the properties.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it MDT-UML2 is in the very early stages, it may not work as it should always.  Additionally, the sequence diagram is a newer one, see below.  There were no tutorial I could find, but I did link to samples below.  I also found a comment in the eclipse bug tracker for this feature:

> Here are the most important issues from my side: moving of lifelines, create messages, 
>   replies are causing strange behaviour (some kind of auto alignment). Moreover it
>   should be possible to give the messages names.

They say it is resolved, but you be the judge.

From the wiki (Note:What you want is UML2 Tools):
http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2Tools

> Interaction diagrams (in progress):
>   Sequence (new in Galileo)

This may not help, but here is a link to the samples: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/3/3a/UML2Tools_samples.psf

The tutorial reference does not seem to cover the new stuff, just the class diagram.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html

Search stackoverflow for other open source tools to use.  The MDT-UML2 is coming along and can be used for some stuff, especially simple DSMs/DSLs/UML Profiles, but for drawing easily there are a host of good tools.  An ok thread: [What's the best UML diagramming tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool) or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse