# What's a good freeware UML diagrams tool supporting automatic class association

Tags: architecture, language-agnostic, uml, class-design

I'm looking for a simple tool that will let me list a few classes, describe the members and methods of each class, the data types of the members, recognize when a data type is another class (e.g if I have a class `Foo` and a member of the class `Bar` is `Foo fooItem` then it will establish a link between `Foo` and `Bar` classes). Any suggestions?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476781/free-uml-tool-for-use) and maybe you can find something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Argo UML and Astah (was Jude)

Answer (score 1):

Give [umbrello](http://www.umbrello.org/index.php) a try. Easy to learn and has many features for uml diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

PlantUML - http://plantuml.com/

Diagrams are defined using simple language.  Can be used within many other tools, editors and development environments.

Can also generate ASCII art which I find useful.  Try the online demo server - http://plantuml.com/plantuml/

```
 ┌───┐          ┌─────┐
 │Bob│          │Alice│
 └─┬─┘          └──┬──┘
   │    hello      │   
   │──────────────>│   
 ┌─┴─┐          ┌──┴──┐
 │Bob│          │Alice│
 └───┘          └─────┘
```

Comment: Example with Classes: http://www.planttext.com/planttext?text=PP3DQiGm38JlUGeTMye6-W0BsqFRMozB3pq54Qk9mNz8IfPG-kwLdHO2lGmUuHb_yaKKMPSOkZ6W2Bpa_0XV7S17Nc3418kGEQ6L60C4dqZCzxq92cnswuP9gqiE9ivBiVFvRAApJvE0vebq9gw9OJWqpxXIxOYOjZqf_qfF9vDdQywVq02xx-wNz5s86sdVmzN74WXUITM63Uu1xDatZ7Ht_-UUd6CIQOCQof5iiMD43f5XWC9-HILmgBYp-wI04pKoe3JoLfJSZdbLjeMX6Dmjiwka5qhE_lO7

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be related to find a tool which can reverse engineer a java code. You don't really have any freeware able to do all what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To @UMLGURU's point, Sparx EA will provide reverse engineering but is not free.  If you just need something tactical then you could perhaps use the free 30 day trial.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html