# UML diagrams, identifying the tool which was used to generate some[images attached]

Tags: uml, identification

Do you have any idea what software was used to generate these UML diagrams? I need to generate exactly the same ones. I had a thought that it might be eUML2, but I have checked the newest version and there is options to create something like that. However, it may have been possible in previous versions.

[image: http://mk74.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/diagram1.jpg]
[image: http://mk74.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/diagram2.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

you can use Gliffy (http://www.gliffy.com/uses/uml-software/) to get very similar ones

A similar question: [What's the best UML diagramming tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool)

Comment: I want to have exactly the same ones.

Comment: you can get exactly the same ones with that if you use it carefully.

Comment: If I use the one which author originally used, I saved a lot of time

Comment: I have already done that. Scientists are quite busy, so I am not so convinced that I am going to get the response.

Comment: Use Edraw software it will help you a lot to create exactly the same model.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. It was created by macromedia freehand.