# Implementation in Eclipse Modeling Framework

Tags: java, uml, ecore

The tools allow us to create interfaces, however, I don't see how to create an implements arrow.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: `how to create an implements arrow??` what does this mean? Your question is not clear

Comment: Have you tried to select your interface as a supertype?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a particular reason to use the eclipse modeling function?

if not, there's plenty other uml tools that are much better in every aspect of your needs.

[What's the best UML diagramming tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool)