# Modelling large scale web-application infrastructure?

Tags: architecture, soa, modeling, n-tier-architecture, worker-process

I am looking for an industry standardised notation and methodology for showing these connections and a little bit of detail as to what data is being transferred at each step.

Here is my ad-hoc diagram, showing the major entities and their relations:

[image: ad-hoc diagram]

I would like to go into a little bit of detail about what each entity does, how; and what it sends/receives.

Maybe this is the sort of thing to use BPMN2 notation for? - Or some meta model encompassing UML2 sequence diagrams?

Looking forward to finding the right notation =]

Answer (score 1):

First off, +1 for doing your drawing, *you know your domain* and that is the **key** to successfully build your suitable representation in any industry standardised notation!

In some circles, what you have created is referred to as the list of **"things" - a scope level description of things that concern the company and affect its direction and purpose.**

The methods are many so my advice is **choose** and **customise** to suit **you**. Use the info hear as learning curves; I have found in some organisations the decision is made on which way to follow and this ends up killing the *natural creativity* in those who attempt to apply the method as the text book recommends.

Notation-wise, UML will offer your project the **Use Case diagrams** to capture instances where the workers (Actors) interfaces with the application. Additionally, since you are after the data flows in your 'info-diagram' I recommend creating a **Domain Model diagram and a supporting Object diagram** that instantiates the domain model with the data attributes you expect to flow. [See my answer to a similar question which includes pictures.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199428/the-proper-uml-model-of-a-system-for-non-technical-boss/199500#199500) *I cannot paste pictures here yet, sorry...*

To help you solve these problems in future I will leave you with a framework to deriving the appropriate steps to take in finding a methodology that will work for you and your team: this is the [Zachman Framework basics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqlLO.jpg) - old school but very effective. Put this on your wall and you will be like, `"I know Kung-Fu!"` in a couple of weeks!

Read the cells from the top-left white box down - thus Data versus Scope. As your audience changes adapt the diagrams to represent the necessary information. This will give you your Model Repository.

[Figure 5 in this document suggests how the core UML metamodel, with its various software analysis and design diagrams, might map to the Zachman Framework.](http://www.bptrends.com/publicationfiles/09-03%20WP%20Mapping%20MDA%20to%20Zachman%20Framework.pdf) This information is priceless and will give you all the concrete basics for building this thought process.

I have learnt that all further forms of methodologies can be derived from here, this is why most times I think Zachman found the ***E=MC^2 of modelling***!

TOGAF, BPMN, EDOC, CWM, SOA, MDA/UML all fit here, so this is truly the foundation to master.

Enjoy the process. You can also refer to [this Q&A to see which UML tool is good for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool)