# UML Dependency relationship

Tags: class, uml, diagram

Why and how are dependency relationships used?

I've come across a [PiggyBank example](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.tutorial.piggybank%2Ftopics%2Fmodule2%2Fexercise2.8_piggybank.html) where the Analysis Model consists of a class diagram with dependency relationships.

They use two relationships "use" and "instantiate" to describe the relationships between the classes.

I don't agree with the relationship that the boundary class TransferMoneyForm  has a "use"  to the TranferMoneControl. I believe it should be the other way around.

Can someone exaplain to me how these two relationships should be used. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**The diagram shown there is not a correct and full UML class diagram.** In such all the associations and generalizations should be defined, and what is abstract, what is public or not. To show what descends from what, what is hidden, what will be never instantiated and what fields of one class has types of other classes. Here we see only information about the 
functions.

And it is logical. If you'll look at the previous chapter, there is written: "A control class represents a self-contained process..." So, they are talking on processes, not classes, instances and fields.

It is NOT a class diagram. And nowhere is said that it is. It is named "Transfer Money Participants diagram". They do use the elements of the class diagram, but not to the fullest and so create something more common. It is some approximate undefined diagram on some classes, something between class, communication or component diagrams. Maybe, it is the old style of IBM? Experts ([What's the best UML diagramming tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool), 1st answer) say, "IBM Rational Software Architect did not implement UML 2.0". )

As for the question, who uses whom... According to Sparx VP UML, a "usage dependency" is a "relationship in which one element requires another element ... for its full functionality". According to wiki, "The client element somehow "uses" the supplier". Here the form hasn't sense without the controlling class, and vice versa. So, I'd say, the use goes in both sides. But more honest would be to create a normal communication or component diagram. The class diagram has NOT an element to say about sending and accepting the messages. And the "use" is definitely not for it. And when they have decided not to use logic, they can put there virtually anything.

**If you are making a class diagram and one your class uses function(s) of another one, that is the case to draw a use dependency connection.**