# Modeling a social website

Tags: uml, social-networking, rup, rational-rose

I have been learning to use Rational Rose Enterprise methodology RUP - UML, I heard that is the most basic one to use. I also know how to use IBM Architect, but I am new to it.
My question is, to diagram a website such as a social network, (Facebook, twitter, etc...) or a complex website, (eBay, olx, etc...) which methodology should I use and which software should I use? I am new to this and any help will be useful.

If you have any websites or books you can recommend it will be helpful.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can use any methodology you like and any tool you like. There's no clear single answer. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools and http://agilemodeling.com/ and http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html

Comment: Perhaps should you improve your question to provide more details about what you are looking for. As suggested my @xmojmr, this is highly related to your development process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any UML tool will help you to build an UML model, which is a software representation. It is up to you to find the right tool. A stackoverflow [exchange on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15376/1207019) exists (event if this is considered non constructive).

It is very difficult to make any recommendation. It depends on what you wish to model. It will be difficult to represent properly a web application on the hypertext point of view.

In UML, a hypertext document is an [artifact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(UML)). This is an UML element which is not specific to hypertext documents. Therefore hyperlinks in the UML world would be traditional UML associations (dependency, composition, etc.).

There is a non-standard solution for modeling hypertext applications: [the hypertext model](http://www.webml.org/webml/page6.do?dau4.oid=4&UserCtxParam=0&GroupCtxParam=0&ctx1=EN) in WebML. That language is progressively standardized in the frame of the OMG with the [IFML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_Flow_Modeling_Language) language. However, as far as I know, the hypertext model is not part of the standard until now. And the support of IFML is quite rare.