# UML software choice

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case, activity-diagram

Currently I'm tasked to research the different options available for creating UML diagrams, but since I have barely worked with them I find it a hard task and would like to ask for some help with the choice considering our scope.

**The Scope**
Use Case and Activity Diagrams have to be presentable to the customers, so they should look decently visually and not like they're from the 90s.
For huge projects where we think they will be important we also have to make Class, ERD and ORM diagrams.
This software should run on Linux distro's

**Question**
I had consider to find a piece of UML software that creates visually attractive diagrams for the Use Case and Activity diagrams. And then use a different piece of software for the in house creation of Class/ERD/ORM with the use of [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). Does anyone here have some experience with UML in a company that might be able to give me feedback that assists me in the creation of a well motivated reason why we should perhaps even purchase a certain piece of software for UML?

My apologies if this question is too open or opinionated.

I've also seen this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools but it is hard to decide just from reading that if I don't have any first hand experience with them.

Also read this question [What's the best UML diagramming tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376/whats-the-best-uml-diagramming-tool?rq=1) but it's 3 years old and doesn't really give any info considering the scope I have to look at.

Visio would pretty much fit all our needs in one software package, the price is just too excessive.

Comment: If you are really interested in getting the best out there, you'd do it like me : go through the wikipedia list you provided and install each app from there and spend some time going through their features and limitations, and also go through [alternatives to argouml](http://alternativeto.net/software/argouml/) and see which one fits with your needs.

Comment: Like I said I don't really have any UML experience, I might be looking at the wrong thing, the purpose of this question is hearing from people who probably have more experience than I have, and might be able to give a answer to my questions for all the right reasons, instead of me possibly picking one for all the wrong ones simply through incompetence.

Comment: Just as a side note, all of our UML/ERD/ORM diagrams are done in jira-confluence by PlantUML. By hand, most of the design changes that we present are on a sheet of paper that we change rapidly in a meeting and if you want some eyecandy for your clients you should go with visio / lucidchart.

Comment: Visio looks great especially for Activity/Use Case diagrams since they look excellent visually. But a huge issue is the high price of the software.

Comment: also omnigroup has awesome apps.

Comment: You should definitely try  https://www.genmymodel.com We have tried to make diagrams visually attractive and to make the tool as easy to use as possible, but with the same level of functionality as desktop tools.